# Active class state not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following rules which apply an active and hover state to a li element:

```
.toolbar ul li.plus {
    background-position: 0 -170px;
}
.toolbar ul li.plus:hover, li.plus.active {
    background-position: -34px -170px;
```

Now my HTML markup works when I hover over it:

```
<li class="plus"><a href="#" data-content="Add property to shortlist" data-trigger="hover" title="">link</a></li>
```

however, if I want to explicitly active it won't work with the following:

```
<li class="plus active"><a href="#" data-content="Add property to shortlist" data-trigger="hover" title="">link</a></li>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`.toolbar ul li.plus` has higher specificity than `li.plus.active`.  You can use

```
.toolbar ul li.plus.active
```